# Extract image areas with skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image

So, I'm studying image processing using skimage kit (for my graduation research), I want to auto-generate "segments" of images. Look at [Simple Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7yOJ.png), you can see three different areas, let's say: If I want to studying only one of three areas, how I do this?

An example is [The only area an I'm have interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36PwP.png), how I can extract this area utilizing skimage kit with python?

It's clear?

Thanks for this.

EDITING:

For says more expecific, I have this image [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeALn.png), It's easy to see that exists three differents areas. I want to generated a image without the black top part and bottom gray part. The **algorithm** isn't my problem, but the **method** it's.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract that area you either use a position feature (if known), or a simple [threshold](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html) if possible. Be aware that this *might* work.

Once you know how to segment this, it's easy: Binarize the image such that each pixel in that area is 1, all other are zero, then sum over all binarized pixels.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I need explore more the docs of skimage.